# Prototype not a valid function

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype

Am I missing something?  I have other prototypes in this same file and they work as expected.

```
module StACS    
    export module NumberPrototypes {
        export function initializer() {
            // OTHER PROTOTYPES REMOVED FOR SPACE

            Number.prototype.toPureNumber = function(): number {
                var self = this;
                return parseFloat(self.toString().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''));
            }
        }
    }
}

interface Number {
    toMoney(decimals?: number, decimalCharacter?: string, thousandsCharacter?: string): string;
    toPercentage(decimals?: number, showSymbol?: boolean): string;
    toPureNumber(): number; 
}
```

My Observable:

```
productPrice: KnockoutObservable<number>:
productsTabView.productModel().productPrice()
```

Result:

```
"$25.00"
```

When I try to do this:

```
productsTabView.productModel().productPrice().toPureNumber()
```

I get the following Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: productsTabView.productModel(...).productPrice(...).toPureNumber is not a function
    at <anonymous>:2:47
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Comment: Shoudn't be this way? Number.prototype.toPureNumber = function(number){ ... }

Comment: Have you called the `initialiser()` already?

Comment: Sorry I had to do some running around.  Yes I call initializer on the page load event.  The other two prototypes I have work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally figured out my issue.  Sadly it's not something anyone here would have probably figured out as you were missing a key part.  Even though the KO Observable is set to a number, I have a custom extender attached to it.  This extender does formatting and returns a String, not a number.

This is why I get this:

```
productsTabView.productModel().productPrice()
"$0.00"
```

I changed the prototype to this:

```
String.prototype.toPureNumber = function (): number {
    var self = this;
    return parseFloat(self.toString().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''));
}
```

And now this works as expected:

```
productsTabView.productModel().productPrice().toPureNumber()
0
```

Answer (score -1):

The following works:

```
interface Number {
    toPureNumber(): number; 
}

Number.prototype.toPureNumber = function(): number {
    var self = this;
    return parseFloat(self.toString().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''));
}

var foo = 123.3;
var bar = foo.toPureNumber();
console.log(bar);
```

## FIX

call `initializer`.

Comment: If you would have read my comment above, there are 2 other prototypes in the initializer function that is being called on the document load event.  The other two prototypes are working.